# Problems validating Regex.IsMatch

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a problem with `regx.Ismatch`. I need to validate an string in this format, `@"[O]-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]"`, I am using this code:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(vm.CadastralNumber, @"[O]-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]"))   
    ModelState.AddModelError("CadastralNumber", "Prefix should be O, or the format is not correct"); .
```

But I got a problem, after that format I need user not to allow to write more number like `-[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]`. It never stops, I need users to write just the format I gave first, ad not to alow writting more -. Any help?

Comment: Where is the LINQ here?

Answer (score 0):

Write it as `@"^[O]-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]$"` to make the regex match the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You must use anchors, `^` (the beginning of a string) and `$` (the end of the string). You can also use a bit cleaner regex:

```
@"^O-\d{8}-\d{5}(?:-\d){3}$"
```

Comment: Note that `\d` in C# matches non-arabic digits like `൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯`.